# How to execute my callback function is a custom Dojo module?

Tags: javascript, function, dojo, callback, scope

I have the code below:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"],function (declare) {
   return declare("tamoio.Map", null, {

     methodA: function(param){
        console.log(param);
        this.methodB('xxx',function(){
          this.methodC(); //it didn't call!
        });
     },

     methodB: function(text, callback){
       alert('do nothing: ' + text);
       callback();
     },

     methodC: function(){
       alert('hello');
     }

   });
});
```

When I run my application I received the messege:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'methodC'
```

How to do I invoke a internal method in my module?

I'm using Dojo 1.9.1

Best regards,

Renan

Comment: guys, I'm pass the function methodC as a callback function then another function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because your callback function is being executed in the global scope (window), and there is no function called `methodC` defined. You need to get `methodC` to execute in the scope of your widget, and there are two ways of doing this:

1.) Take advantage of JavaScript closures:

```
 methodA: function(param){
   console.log(param);
   var self = this;   // Create a reference to the widget's context.
   this.methodB('xxx',function(){
     self.methodC();  // Use the widget scope in your anonymous function.
   });
 }
```

2.) Take advantage of the [dojo/_base/lang](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) module's `hitch` method:

```
 methodA: function(param){
   console.log(param);
   this.methodB('xxx', lang.hitch(this, function(){
     this.methodC(); 
   }));
 }
```

The `hitch` method returns a function that will be executed in the context provided, in this case it is `this` (the widget).

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help. JavaScript scoping takes some time to get used to.